# HOW to Code "If textbox is not empty then Msgbox "Invalid"

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, is-empty, msgbox

I need help in coding this

"If textbox is not empty then Msgbox "Invalid"

I know empty is "" but how do  I write not empty?
Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question to include a [MCVE] so we have some scope of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic question. Try `TEXTBOX<>""`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Me.TextBox1 <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid"
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also utilize `LEN()` function.

```
If Len(Me.TextBox1) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid"
End If
```

Comment: Sorry I am new with VBA could you please tell me what does Me in `Me.Textbox1` represent here ?

Comment: @Damandeep Me represent current form you are working on. You can also use form name like `UserForm1.TextBox1`. Even you can use textbox name only like `If Len(TextBox1) > 0 Then ...`

Comment: I have one inputbox if its empty do I have to  start with Me.InputBox ?

Comment: @Damandeep https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword

Comment: You said in question about `textbox` but telling inputbox now? Please correct your question first.

Comment: @Harun24HR i didnt ask this question. i am just randomly checking VBA tagged questions

Comment: @Damandeep the `Me` keyword is an implicit reference to the `Sheet`, `Class`, `Form` etc. for the module your code is being written in. e.g. if your code is in the `Sheet1` module, `Me.Range()` is the same as `Sheet1.Range()` or if your code is in the module for `UserForm1` then `Me.Hide` is the same as `UserForm1.Hide`

Comment: @Damandeep if you have a coding question, ask it as a question, not in a comment thread :)

Comment: @Damandeep For inputbox you can try `If Len(InputBox("Enter data.")) > 0 Then`.

Comment: @SamuelEverson ok